# Configure SPF and DNS Reverse

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reverse, spf

Context :
My registar is OVH.
My server is an EC2 instance (AWS).
I'm using SES to send emails.

I've lanuch a test with http://www.mail-tester.com/ and this tool told me to :

- Configure the SPF :
  mydomain.fr: Sender is not authorized by default to use 'hello@mydomain.fr' in 'mfrom' identity, however domain is not currently prepared for false failures (mechanism '~all' matched)
  Configuration (OVH) :

  .mydomain.fr
  SPF 
  v=spf1 a mx include:amazonses.com ~all
- Configure the reverse DNS :

Where must I configure this ? OVH my registar ? Amazon ? Both ?

- Configure DKIM

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are hosting your domain. It sounds like it's OVH.

Unless you are using Route 53 as a domain forwarder you don't need to configure anything on Amazon for DNS.

Also make sure your domain, emails and senders are authorized on Amazon SES. (You can do it from the AWS console as seen on the screenshots samples below)

[image: Authorize domain SES]

[image: Authorize emails SES]